# find position of item in for loop over a sequence

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the index in Python for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

```
list = [1,2,2,3,5,5,6,7]

for item in mylist:
    ...
```

How can I find the index of the item I am looking at, at some point in my loop? I can see there is a `index()` method for `lists` but it will always give me the first index of a value, so it won't work for lists with duplicate items

Comment: Duplicate; check if someone else asked it already before you ask it. Google is a friend of mine (google is my friend!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

```
>>> for i, season in enumerate('Spring Summer Fall Winter'.split(), start=1):
        print i, season
1 Spring
2 Summer
3 Fall
4 Winter
```

Answer (score 6):

Use an enumerator object:

```
for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
  ...
```